# how can i call refresh method

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, refresh, reload

the question is like this
i init a jqgrid without **postData** ,
and set **hiddengrid:true,**

i want to init table at first with no request,
then will request data by hand,

**js**

```
var showRoleList = function($entityList,pagerId)
{
    $entityList.jqGrid({
        url:'servlet/RoleAction',
        datatype: 'json',
        height: 'auto',
        jsonReader:
        {
            repeatitems : false,
            userdata: "rows"
        },
        colNames:['ID','roleName','detail','action'],
        colModel:
        [
            {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,sortable:false},
            {name:'description',index:'description', width:400,sortable:false},
            {name:'action',index:'action', width:40,sortable:false}
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        altRows:true,
        autowidth:true,
        mtype: "POST",
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 30,
        imgpath:'css/images',
        sortorder:'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
         multiselect:true,
        loadui:'disable' ,
        gridview:true,
        hiddengrid:true,
        page:1,
        pginput:true,
        pager: pagerId,
        sortname: 'dateEntered',
        altclass:'ui-priority-secondary_1',
    });
}

showRoleList($("#entityList0"),"#pEntityList0");
**$entityList0.jqGrid("setGridParam", {  
       postData:{ACTION:'userRelation',userId:user.id,typeName:'role',flag:true},
});**

 **$entityList0.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}]);**
```

**html**:

```
<table id="entityList0"></table>
<div id="pEntityList0"></div>
```

but failed 
when i called trigger, request can be sent,but without postData

no param can post to server

but if i click refresh button  it can work

how can i resolve this question

thank you for you answer

Comment: Could you post more full code which you use? The best information is which one can use to reproduce your problem. One don't really need have any server components. One can just see which HTTP request will be sent.

Comment: thank you  i add more information

Comment: This code should work as-is. `trigger("reloadGrid")` does *almost* exactly what the Refresh button does anyway. Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem. The only clear syntax error is `flag:true},})` muss be replaced to `flag:true}})` (remove comma). In the same way you should replace `altclass:'ui-priority-secondary_1',}` to `altclass:'ui-priority-secondary_1'}`.

Is all the code inside of `$(document).ready(function() {/*here*/});`?

In the code variables `user` and `$entityList0` are not initialized. Are you sure, that use set `$entityList0=$("#entityList0")` and initialize `user` at least as `{}` in the code above?

You should also remove deprecated `imgpath` parameter and replace `sortname: 'dateEntered'` to `sortname: 'name'` for example.

If you post any test data which you use I could give you url to the code which you posted and which work at me without any problem.

**UPDATED**: OK! Now having the code which one can test I see where your problem is. The problem is that you try to start **the second ajax request before the first one is ended**.

Your grid has `datatype: 'json'`. In the line `showRoleList($entityList0,'#pEntityList0');` you start the first ajax request and then immediately start the second one with respect of `$entityList0.trigger("reloadGrid")`. The first request set internal variable `$("#entityList0")[0].grid.hDiv.loading` to true and all other requests which you start will be just ignored till the timeout or the response or error returned from the server.

Probably you not really want to send the first request till you set the `postData` parameters. So you should use **`datatype: 'local'`** at the initialization time of jqGrid (in the `showRoleList` function). Then you should set `datatype: 'json'` additionally to the `postData`:

```
$entityList0.jqGrid(
    "setGridParam",
    {
        datatype: 'json',
        postData: {
            ACTION:'userRelation',
            userId:'1111',
            typeName:'role',
            flag:true
        }
    }
);
```

Alternative you will need to abort the previous ajax call before reloading of the grid. If it is really needed I could explain how you can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

ok  i just make a test.html

```
 <html ... 
    <script  type="text/javascript"> 
    var $entityList0;  
     $(function(){

       $entityList0 = $("#entityList0");          
       showRoleList($entityList0,'#pEntityList0');         
       $entityList0.jqGrid("navGrid",'#pEntityList0',{});         
       $entityList0.jqGrid("setGridParam",
        {     
             postData:{ACTION:'userRelation',userId:'1111',typeName:'role',flag:true}
        }).showCol("action");   
        $entityList0.trigger("reloadGrid"); 
        });  
var showRoleList = function($entityList,pagerId) {
            $entityList.jqGrid({
                url:'servlet/RoleAction',
                datatype: 'json',       height: 'auto',
                jsonReader:         {
                    repeatitems : false,
                    userdata: "rows"
                },
                colNames:['ID','roleName','detail','actiokn'],
                colModel:
                [
                    {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true},
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,sortable:false},
                    {name:'description',index:'description',
        width:400,sortable:false},
                    {name:'action',index:'action',
        width:40,sortable:false}
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                altRows:true,
                autowidth:true,
                mtype: "POST",
                rownumbers: true,       rownumWidth: 30,
                //imgpath:'css/images',
                sortorder:'desc',
                viewrecords: true,
                 multiselect:true,
                loadui:'disable' ,
                gridview:true,
                hiddengrid:true,
                page:1,
                pginput:true,
                pager: pagerId,
                sortname: 'dateEntered',        altclass:'ui-priority-secondary_1',
            }); } </script> 
</head> 
<body>
          <table id="entityList0"></table>
           <div id="pEntityList0"></div>        
</body> 
</html>
```

when the first time open the url test.html

```
    HeadersPostPutHTMLXML
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    _search false
    nd  1300458295847
    page    1
    rows    10
    sidx    dateEntered
    sord    desc

_search=false&nd=1300458295847&rows=10&page=1&sidx=dateEntered&sord=desc
```

an then i click refresh button

```
HeadersPostPutHTML
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
ACTION  userRelation
_search false
flag    true
nd  1300458310960
page    1
rows    10
sidx    dateEntered
sord    desc
typeName    role
userId  1111

_search=false&nd=1300458310960&rows=10&page=1&sidx=dateEntered&sord=desc&ACTION=userRelation&userId=1111&typeName=role&flag=true
```

you can test it

you can see  the result is different
this is a simple page ,you can test easily ! if you can find something wrong  please tell me  thank you